# Multiple images resizing toupload folder in Codeiniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this controller which inserts the images to upload folder without resizing them.

```
public Function Upload() {
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/property-images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['file_name']      = 'property_image_1';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
          $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
          $_FILES['uploadedimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
          $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
          $_FILES['uploadedimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
          $_FILES['uploadedimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimage', $i)) {

$data['uploadedimage'] = $this->upload->data();
$image_name[$i] = $data['uploadedimage']['file_name'];
//$this->_property_images_resize($data); // Private Function For Resize
$data['images'] = implode(',',$image_name);

$this->model_users->insert_property_details($data))
redirect('view');
  } else {
$this->form_validation->set_message('fileupload_check', $this->upload->display_errors());
return FALSE;
  }
}
}
```

I further needed to resize the images with the help of a private function in controller:

```
private function _property_images_resize($data) {
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config = array(
    'image_library'     => 'gd2',
    'source_image'      => 'uploads/property-images/'.$data['uploadedimage']['file_name'],
    'new_image'         => 'uploads/profile/test1/',
    'create_thumb'      => TRUE,
    'maintain_ratio'    => TRUE,
    'width'             => 10,
    'height'            => 10
    );
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize()) echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

After adding this second function, it changes nothing. Images uploads the way they were before without resizing.

Looking for someone's help as can't figure it out.

For validation Callback

```
function if_image_was_selected(){
$this->form_validation->set_message('if_image_was_selected', 'Please select at least 1 image in jpg/jpeg/png/gif format.');
$number_of_files = count($_FILES['uploadedimages']['tmp_name']);
    $files = $_FILES['uploadedimages'];
    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++) {
      if($_FILES['uploadedimages']['error'][$i] != 0) {
    return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your not suppose to call:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

instead of

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Does your webserver user have write permissions to the **uploads/profile/test1/** directory?

Do you get any error message?  Have you checked the PHP log or Apache log?

Try adding this code below, above your code to see the error echo'd out to the screen if you can.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks... I changed it to `$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);`.. Added error reporting... No errors.. Posts successfully without resize.. Yes folder has write permission as other images are getting uploaded.. I am running Xampp.. Do you think it could be because $data is an array of multiple images? Because same function worked for one of my another controller where I had to just resize 1 profile image.

Comment: Try  
var_dump($data);  to see what its set to.  If its null, that will give you a clue that its not even getting the data

Comment: Do you think your missing an ending slash in your config?

Comment: $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/property-images';

Comment: should it be $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/property-images/';

Comment: Where is the variable $number_of_files set?

Comment: var_dump gives `array(1) { ["uploadedimage"]=> array(14) { ["file_name"]=> string(21) "property_image_15.jpg" ["file_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["file_path"]=> string(46) "C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/uploads/property-images/" ["full_path"]=> string(67) "C:/xampp/htdocs/admin/uploads/property-images/property_image_15.jpg" ["raw_name"]=> string(17) "property_image_15" ["orig_name"]=> string(20) "property_image_1.jpg" ["client_name"]=> string(5) "1.jpg" ["file_ext"]=> string(4) ".jpg" ["file_size"]=> float(3.44)"" } }`

Comment: $number_of_files is a call back through form validation.. Just added in the question..

Comment: in the function _property_images_resize , do you need the fullpath to the directories?

Comment: 'source_image' => FCPATH.'uploads/property-images/'.$data['uploadedimage']['file_name'],

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102801/discussion-between-codeigniter-learner-and-phpdave).